# In Wix, how to move a form from one page to another

Tags: forms, move, velo

In Wix, I have created and added a form on a page. Now I would like to move this form to another page, not sure how to do that.

I tried to cut this form from the original page, and pasted it on the target page. However after doing that, I can on the Wix Dashboard a new data collection is created under the Form section, "Registration Form 2", but the original data collection still exists (i.e. "Registration Form". How can that happens?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NWRV.png)